# Entity Data Source connection string as a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How can I set an Entity Data Source connection string from a variable set in the codebehind page.

e.g. something like this in the code behind

```
string edsconstring = "name=EDSEntities";
```

and then in the aspx

```
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="UnAuthPricesEDS" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString=<%= this.edsconstring %> DefaultContainerName="CS3Entities" 
            EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CustomersItems" Where="it.Authorised=false"
            OrderBy="it.DateSet" >
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: I get "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs."

Comment: Change it to `public string edsconstring = "name=EDSEntities";`

Comment: I still get the "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs." even with a public string

Comment: Keep Quotes like this `ConnectionString="<%= this.edsconstring %>"`

Comment: Keyword not supported: '<%'.

Comment: As per my past experience I'm giving these hints:) Change it to `ConnectionString="<%# this.edsconstring %>"`

Comment: Now getting: The ObjectContext must be configured by 1) defining ContextTypeName, 2) defining both ConnectionString and DefaultContainerName, 3) defining ContextType, or 4) supplying it in the OnSelecting event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63023/discussion-between-venkata-panga-and-gordon-copestake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case try this with CodeExpressionbuilder

Add this Class:

```
[ExpressionPrefix("Code")]
public class CodeExpressionBuilder : ExpressionBuilder {
    public override CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry, 
       object parsedData, ExpressionBuilderContext context) {
        return new CodeSnippetExpression(entry.Expression);
    }
}
```

ASPX Markup: [observe `ConnectionString="<%$ Code: edsconstring %>"`]

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="UnAuthPricesEDS" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ Code: edsconstring %>" DefaultContainerName="CS3Entities" 
            EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CustomersItems" Where="it.Authorised=false"
            OrderBy="it.DateSet" >
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

**Another Case:** by using [ConnectionStringExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/The-CodeExpressionBuilder) so you can refer to Connection Strings defined in the new connection strings section in the web.config. That is extremely helpful when working with the new declarative data controls:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="UnAuthPricesEDS" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: MyConfigConnectionString %>" DefaultContainerName="CS3Entities" 
            EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CustomersItems" Where="it.Authorised=false"
            OrderBy="it.DateSet" >
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: Venkata, where does my string go in this solution?

Comment: See I've updated answer for CodeExpressionbuilder `<%$ Code: edsconstring %>`